# Boot into recovery console

Tags: 11.04, drivers, nvidia

I found out that since my brand new Alienware M17xR3 laptop is running Intel Sandy Bridge, I have two options to get it to work:

1. Run 11.04 which has experimental Sandy Bridge support in the kernel
2. Disable nVidia Optimus if I want to use nvidia driver

Option 2 is not possible because there is no option in the BIOS even though I have already updated to the latest version from Dell's support site.

Thus, it comes to my question: my attempt to install 11.04 works until I have to reboot. After which all I see is a brief image of the Ubuntu logo with 5 dots. Then, the screen keeps flickering like crazy with different colors. How do I boot up my Ubuntu with a barebone, no frill so I can keep running `apt-get upgrade` every couple of days?

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit your grub2 menu to boot into a console rather than auto-start the GUI.

I haven't fooled with 11.04 yet, but I think you need to edit /etc/default/grub as root to give you a terminal upon booting.

Try the instructions here: http://ubuntuguide.net/boot-into-consolecommand-line-when-startup-ubuntu-9-10 It's for an earlier version, but I think it uses grub2 also.

If you need to get to a command prompt so you can edit grub, download and burn the "ultimate boot CD", which has tomsrtbt on it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem can be solved much more simply by installing the kernel from the 11.04 repository.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v2.6.28/
or
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/linux-image-2.6.38-8-generic